# Edit Form in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, populate

I'm trying to use form to fill it from database and user can edit information. I add model named "*Number*" :
**Number.php:**

```
<?php
class Model_Number extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'cc_number';
    protected $_schema = 'general'; 
}
```

In this table (cc_number) , I have three field : "*id , number , country*"
within application/forms, I add this form:
**EditNumber.php:**

```
<?php
Class Form_EditNumber extends Zend_Form 
{
    public function __construct($option = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($option);
        $this->setName('edit_number');
        $message = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('message');
        $message->setLabel(' number :')
                  ->setRequired(true);

        $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('country');
        $country->setLabel(' country name :')
                  ->setRequired(true);
        $login = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login');
        $login ->setLabel('edit ');
        $this ->addElements(array($message,$login));
        $this->setMethod('post');
    }
}
```

In controller , I've tried to get number from last part of URL , and then get information from this number:

**Number/editAction:**

```
        public function editAction(){
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $form_number = new Form_EditNumber();
            $uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
            $part = basename($uri);
            $numberModel = new Model_Number();
            $select = $numberModel->fetchRow($numberModel->select()->where("number =  '$part'"));
            $this->view->edit_form = $form_number->populate($select->toArray());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not get the `$part` from the Uri in that way.
It should come from the `$_GET` part of the request

Can you `print_r` the contents of `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()` because that way you might get the `$part`.

Answer (score 0):

To get values from request, use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('ParamName');` in controller, where `ParamName` is the name of the last param with the number you want.

```
$part = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ParamName');
```

Then in the query you need to pass this value like this:

```
 $select = $numberModel->fetchRow($numberModel->select()->where("number = ". $part));
```

Tip: Its better to use PDO